# Moving VSE sequences between files

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am making a series of educational videos for my lab and have a separate blender file for each chapter. I have created an opening sequence that uses multiple lines of text that I metastrip-ed together. I would like to avoid reformatting the opening text for each file - positioning and sizing them to all be identical - for each chapter. Is there a way to copy the metastrip from one file and move to another?

I've been researching this problem for a few hours and realized that maybe I should have setup all the chapters in one file as different scenes. It appears you can move metastrips between scenes of the same file. Different facet of the same problem here - would there be a way to move all the work I've done from the VSE in one file to another. Append doesn't seem to work - just nothing shows up when I append a scene. Copy and Paste doesn't work. Would I have to export the file as something other than a .blend file and import into the other file? Would that save the ability to edit the text (since each chapter has a different title)?

Any help is appreciated. Maybe I just don't know what language to use, because I found very little info about this online.

Thanks in advance,
April

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q: Is there a way to copy the metastrip from one file and move to another?**

Yes. You can *Append* a *Scene* from one blend file to another and copy&paste its *(meta)strips* you want, between scenes of current blend file.

---

Blender 2.8x and newer - if I open a blend and go to File > **Append** I can navigate to saved blend and choose existing Scene.A and Scene.B (from attached blend file here). From thouse appended scenes I can **Copy** <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> any strip (image, text, color ... or metastrip) and **Paste** <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> into another scene of the same blend file.

[image]

---

**Note:** Just to prevent confusion. When you are in *VSE* editor and press *Add* <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Scene* this operator adds a strip with *Camera* view from *3Dview* editor includede Compositor result as well (when used).

Like here I created *Scene.C* in a new blend, appended *Scene.B*, then copy-paste text strip to Scene.C and added **"Scene" strip** (that's 3Dview scene - default cube with Normal Matcap, plus Blur node in Node Compositor).

[image]

Comment: Aha. I realize now what my misunderstanding was. I was expecting that when I appended a scene, it would show up in my current scene. I now realize that an appended scene is added as a separate scene and that I can navigate to it from the scene drop down. Learning lots about how to use scenes! Thanks!

As a separate question about workflow, do people tend to use one file with multiple scenes for large projects, or to use multiple files with fewer scenes to keep file sizes lower?

Comment: I don't think someone can give you an answer to this :) Some projects are easier to handle with several scenes some with linked parts from other blend files. Sometimes the criterium is how large project is, sometimes how many people needs to share (or to work with) these parts of projects. You can open it as regular question on this site, but you would have to specify circumstances of your project :)